# What is sponsored listings?

Tags: advertising

I went to a domain once (surprise) and I saw a "sponsored listings" list. It did not appear to be from the website owner, but from a third party. What exactly are "sponsored listings". Are they good? Or bad? PS. I had to disable my adblocker to see them.
[image: A screenshot of sponsored listings]

Comment: It’s the listings where one company A pays to others to get link to company A. Usually this technique is used for link building purpose. It’s quite old and outdated now, unless you get natural links from very high authoritative domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a Parking Page that you are seeing.

When someone owns a domain and parks it (Usually points the nameservers to parking company nameservers) the parking company shows ads on that page. And earnings from this ads is credited to that domain owners account after parking company deducts its own commission from the earnings.

Usually this sponsored listings are supplied via PPC Feed providers.

I used to work for a parking company so can assure you that this links are not backlinks they usually point to another page hosted on parking company's domain or PPC providers domain. (For statistical analysis etc) and thus No link juice is flowing through it.